# Cannot run scp.exe command from perl script under windows 10 64bit

Tags: windows, perl

I am trying to download a file from a remote server using the following command

```
scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:\temp\fileNEW.txt"
```

If I open a command prompt and run the command the file is downloaded. However, I need to put the command in a perl script. if I put the following commands in a perl script

```
my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:\temp\fileNEW.txt"';
system(qq($Var1));
```

where the folder c:\temp exists on the local machine running the perl command.

Then I get the following error

```
CreateProcessW failed error:2
posix_spawn: No such file or directory
```

Changing $Var1 to

```
my $Var1='scp';
```

and running the script produces

```
usage: scp [-346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
       [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target
```

From this I have deduced that there is some sort of syntax error in my initial definition of $Var1

If I use any of the following values for $Var1

```
my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk"';

my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt"';
```

I get the same output

```
usage: scp [-346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
       [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target
```

However, if I try any of the following:

```
my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:\temp\fileNEW.txt"';

my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:\\temp\\fileNEW.txt"';

my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:/temp/fileNEW.txt"';

my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:\fileNEW.txt"';

my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:\\fileNEW.txt"';

my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:/fileNEW.txt"';

my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:\temp"';

my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:\\temp"';

my $Var1='scp -i "c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk" user1@server.org:"/home/user1/file1.txt" "c:/temp"';
```

I get the error

```
CreateProcessW failed error:2
posix_spawn: No such file or directory
```

So, is the problem the output folder or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the double quotes on the first argument are not removed if you use the 1-arg form of [`system()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). Try to pass the arguments in an array instead:

```
system('scp', '-i', 'c:\users\userX\keyfile.ppk', 'user1@server.org:/home/user1/file1.txt', 'c:\temp\fileNEW.txt');
```

Comment: Many thanks but unfortunately if I use your method I still get the original error message.

Comment: How did you install `scp`? If you let me know I can try it on my machine

Comment: I think it was already installed...anyway it's in the folder c:\windows\system32\openssh along with ssh.exe etc.

Comment: @Chazg76 Yes it was already installed on my machine also. The `scp` command  worked for me after generating keys with [PuTTYgen](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/windows/puttygen). I did not use a `.ppk` file and just typed in the password in the command prompt

Comment: Can you please try ProxyCommand option with an absolute path or a path relative to the ssh.exe.  please refer this URL https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/  and this url https://superuser.com/questions/174160/scp-over-a-proxy-with-one-command-from-local-machine